# Eclipse failing to delete temp directory in VOB while building plug-in jar

Tags: clearcase

I have an issue with exporting plug-in jar in eclipse PDE: When I try to export plug-in jar, Its failing with the errors like

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
xyzlocation\build.xml:63: Unable to delete file xyzlocation temp.folder\@dot.bin\...x.class
```

Here that location is ClearCase VOB.
Eclipse failing to delete the temp directory from the VOB while building the plug-in jar.
I tried the some of the alternatives,could not find the solution.
How would you prevent that error?

Comment: Please provide in your question the exact full path (replacing the name of directories if there is confidentiality issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- the full path of that temp directory within a vob is a path referenced by a ClearCase view (dynamic or snapshot one).
- the temp directory is not *directly* within a view (at the same level than a vob), but actually inside the vob.

Comment: thanks for reply.. Yes the path is referenced by dynamic view.

Comment: @user2599178 any chance to get the full complete path of that temp directory? (starting with `M:\MyView\myVob\...`) even if you change names of the folders if you need to)

Comment: the full path like this M:\vobname\proj_name\temp.folder\@dot.bin\x\xyz.class.  Here M referenced to dynamic view.

Comment: @user2599178 the '`@`' is strange, is it part of the name of the `dot.bin` folder?

Comment: yes VonC. I can see that folder in clearcase explorer with the name '@dot.bin' under temp.folder